# Prevent proxy credentials being written to world-readable file during install?

Tags: system-installation, proxy

I'm provisioning a server for a side project at work, and the Ubuntu 18.04 installer has a *Configure proxy* screen that looks like this:

[image]

Because my employer uses an authenticating HTTP proxy, I've been entering my credentials here.

The install proceeds just fine, but I've noticed that my username and password wind up being written—in clear text—to the following world-readable files:

- `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`
- `/etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/snap_proxy.conf`

My plan was to write an Ansible playbook to take the system from a fresh install to my desired configuration, so removing my credentials in this playbook *is* an option. But I would rather find a way to avoid the need to do so.

Is there some way I can use the company proxy during installation, but *not* have my credentials persisted in clear text?